# Unable to read special characters from xml using java

Tags: java

When i try to read the xml from java using SAX parser, it is unable to read the content in element present after special character

For ex:

```
<title>It's too difficult</title>
```

After reading using the SAX parser, it's displaying only **It**

How to handle special characters. My sample code is as below

```
    package com.test.java;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
public class ReadXMLUsingSAXParser {




  public static void main(String argv[]) {

   try {

      SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
      SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

      DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

      int titleCount;
      boolean title = false;
      boolean description = false;

      public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
         String qName, Attributes attributes)
         throws SAXException {

        // System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);


         if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
            title = true;
            titleCount+=1;
         }

         if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
            description = true;
         }

      }

      public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
           String qName)
           throws SAXException {

         //  System.out.println("End Element :" + qName);

      }

      public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
          throws SAXException {


           if (title&&titleCount>2) {
               System.out.println("title : "
                   + new String(ch, start, length)+":"+titleCount);
               title = false;
            }

           if (description) {
               System.out.println("description : "
                   + new String(ch, start, length));
               description = false;
            }

         }

       };

       saxParser.parse("C:\\Documents and Settings\\sukumar\\Desktop\\sample.xml", handler);

     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }

 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567636/java-sax-parser-split-calls-to-characters/4567654#4567654

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `characters(char ch[], int start, int length)` methode does not read full lines, you should store the characters in a `StringBuffer` and use it in the `endElemen` method.

E.g.:

```
private StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
       String qName)
       throws SAXException {

     if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
        System.out.println("title: " + buffer);
     }else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
        System.out.println("description: " + buffer);
     }
     buffer = new StringBuffer();
}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
      throws SAXException {
     buffer.append(new String(ch, start, length));
}
```