# Java parse xml file when node inner text is html

Tags: java, html, xml, saxparser

Right now I'm using SAXParser with my own handler, it can parse all node values except for the one that has type="html"

My characters function is like this:

```
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        if(content){
        String tmp = new String(ch, start, length);
        System.out.println("Content : " + tmp);
        content = false;
        }
```

And that particular node has the following format, which my output always just give me a bunch of \n and nothing else.

```
   <content type="html">

    &lt;img alt="" src="http://cdn2.sbnation.com/entry_photo_images/8767829/stranger-bad-robot-screencap_large.png" /&gt;


     &lt;p&gt;Bad Robot, the production company founded by geek culture hitmaker J.J. Abrams (&lt;i&gt;Lost&lt;/i&gt;, &lt;i&gt;Fringe&lt;/i&gt;, &lt;i&gt;Star Trek: Into Darkness&lt;/i&gt;, &lt;i&gt;Alias&lt;/i&gt;,&amp;nbsp;etc.), has released a&amp;nbsp;&lt;a href="http://youtu.be/FWaAZCaQXdo" target="_blank"&gt;mysterious new trailer&lt;/a&gt; titled "Stranger." The creepy and inscrutable video spot, posted by the official Bad Robot Twitter account this afternoon, features a starry sky; a long-haired, rope-bound man wandering along a desolate monochromatic shore line; and your garden variety, horrifying stitched-mouth person coming into focus. "Men are erased and reborn," intones a narrator that sounds a little like Leonard Nimoy.&lt;/p&gt;
     &lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;



    </content>
```

Comment: Is this a java question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be wrongfully assuming that the `characters` callback occurs only once in between `startElement` and `endElement` callbacks. It is actually called multiple times.

Since you use the `content` boolean member to determine whether to print stuff or not and also set this same member to `false` inside `characters` callback, your condition is bound to be fulfilled only once, until you reset `content` (it is not clear where you do that).

Here's an example that works with your XML just fine (assumes non-mixed content and Java programming language):

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class TestSaxParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        String xml = 
            "<content type=\"html\">\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    &lt;img alt=\"\" src=\"http://cdn2.sbnation.com/entry_photo_images/8767829/stranger-bad-robot-screencap_large.png\" /&gt;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "     &lt;p&gt;Bad Robot, the production company founded by geek culture hitmaker J.J. Abrams (&lt;i&gt;Lost&lt;/i&gt;, &lt;i&gt;Fringe&lt;/i&gt;, &lt;i&gt;Star Trek: Into Darkness&lt;/i&gt;, &lt;i&gt;Alias&lt;/i&gt;,&amp;nbsp;etc.), has released a&amp;nbsp;&lt;a href=\"http://youtu.be/FWaAZCaQXdo\" target=\"_blank\"&gt;mysterious new trailer&lt;/a&gt; titled \"Stranger.\" The creepy and inscrutable video spot, posted by the official Bad Robot Twitter account this afternoon, features a starry sky; a long-haired, rope-bound man wandering along a desolate monochromatic shore line; and your garden variety, horrifying stitched-mouth person coming into focus. \"Men are erased and reborn,\" intones a narrator that sounds a little like Leonard Nimoy.&lt;/p&gt;\n" +
            "     &lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    </content>";

        MySaxHandler handler = new MySaxHandler();
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();        
        InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
        parser.parse(source, handler);
    }

    private static class MySaxHandler extends DefaultHandler {
        private StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            content.setLength(0);
        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
            content.append(ch, start, length);
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
            System.out.println(content.toString());
        }

    }    
}
```

Output:

```
    <img alt="" src="http://cdn2.sbnation.com/entry_photo_images/8767829/stranger-bad-robot-screencap_large.png" />


     <p>Bad Robot, the production company founded by geek culture hitmaker J.J. Abrams (<i>Lost</i>, <i>Fringe</i>, <i>Star Trek: Into Darkness</i>, <i>Alias</i>,&nbsp;etc.), has released a&nbsp;<a href="http://youtu.be/FWaAZCaQXdo" target="_blank">mysterious new trailer</a> titled "Stranger." The creepy and inscrutable video spot, posted by the official Bad Robot Twitter account this afternoon, features a starry sky; a long-haired, rope-bound man wandering along a desolate monochromatic shore line; and your garden variety, horrifying stitched-mouth person coming into focus. "Men are erased and reborn," intones a narrator that sounds a little like Leonard Nimoy.</p>
     <p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `StringBuffer` to store content as it's described in these topics:

[SAX parsing and special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336140/sax-parsing-and-special-characters)

[Unable to read special characters from xml using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681149/unable-to-read-special-characters-from-xml-using-java)