# Java SAX is not parsing properly

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

I would appreciate any help on this.
This is my first handler I wrote.

I got I REST Webservice returning XML of links. It has quite simple structure and is not deep.
I wrote a handler for this:

```
public class SAXHandlerLnk extends DefaultHandler {

    public List<Link> lnkList = new ArrayList();
    Link lnk = null;
    private StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    //Triggered when the start of tag is found.
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equals("link")) {
            lnk = new Link();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equals("link")) {
            lnkList.add(lnk);
        }
        else if (qName.equals("applicationCode")) {
            lnk.applicationCode = content.toString();
        }
        else if (qName.equals("moduleCode")) {
            lnk.moduleCode = content.toString();
        }
        else if (qName.equals("linkCode")) {
            lnk.linkCode = content.toString();
        }
        else if (qName.equals("languageCode")) {
            lnk.languageCode = content.toString();
        }
        else if (qName.equals("value")) {
            lnk.value = content.toString();
        }
        else if (qName.equals("illustrationUrl")) {
            lnk.illustrationUrl = content.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        content.append(ch, start, length);
    }
}
```

Some XML returned can be empty eg.  or . When this happens my handler unfortunatelly adds previous value to the Object lnk. So when  is empty in XML, I got lnk.illustrationUrl = content; equal to lnk.value.

```
Link{applicationCode='onedownload', moduleCode='onedownload',...}
```

In the above example, I would like moduleCode to be empty or null, because in XML it is an empty tag.

Here is the calling class:

```
public class XMLRepositoryRestLinksFilterSAXParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SAXParserFactory parserFactor = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = parserFactor.newSAXParser();
        SAXHandlerLnk handler = new SAXHandlerLnk();
        parser.parse({URL}, handler);

        for ( Link lnk : handler.lnkList){
            System.out.println(lnk);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that your XML does not contain mixed content, simply clear your `content` variable on each `startElement()` callback.

Comment: that was trivial :). THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like stated in my comment, you'd do the following. The callbacks are usually called in `startElement`, `characters`, (nested?), `characters`, `endElement` order, where (nested?) represents an optional repeat of the entire sequence.

```java
@Override
//Triggered when the start of tag is found.
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    content = null;
    if (qName.equals("link")) {
        lnk = new Link();
    }        
}
```

Note that `characters` may be called multiple times per a single XML element in your document, so your current code might fail to capture all content. You'd be better off using a `StringBuilder` instead of a `String` object to hold your character content and append to it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18467800/878469) for an example.

Comment: thank you for a hint with StringBuilder too, I already edited the code above to improve it