# Sax characters breaking element apart

Tags: java, sax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JAVA SAX parser split calls to characters()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567636/java-sax-parser-split-calls-to-characters)

I have an XML file with the following syntax:

```
<tag ...>
a bunch of text here
<tag ...>
```

There aren't any closing tags for `tag`. I'm grabbing the text in-between the two tags, and storing them in a `List<String>` in `characters ()`. It works for the most part, but on some xml files, it reads a line terminator or something, that breaks the text into two; rather than storing a single entry, "a bunch of text here", I get two entries: "a bunch of", and "text here". The difference is that unlike all the other entries, it doesn't store a line break after "a bunch of", or before "text here".

I need to fix this, but don't know how. I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser is allowed to call the ContentHandler characters method multiple times for each string of element text, it's not finding a line terminator necessarily. [the Java tutorial on SAX](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2000/jw-0804-sax.html) has a short explanation of the characters method:

> Parsers are not required to return any particular number of characters at one time. A parser can return anything from a single character at a time up to several thousand and still be a standard-conforming implementation. So if your application needs to process the characters it sees, it is wise to have the characters() method accumulate the characters in a java.lang.StringBuffer and operate on them only when you are sure that all of them have been found.

Also [this Javaworld article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2000/jw-0804-sax.html) has good explanations and examples.

Comment: I just read about this "feature" now in another post. How do I best fix this? Just add the text to the `List<String>` on the next call to `startElement`? or can the other chunks be called in after another `startElement`? How do I know "all of them have been found"?

Comment: you can store the characters read in in a stringbuffer. you know they're all found when you find the end of the element.

Comment: @anonymous: oops, meant "you know they're all found when you find the start of the next element", since apparently your tags are nested

Comment: thanks. i got it to work. used a `static StringBuilder`, and just kept appending in `characters ()`. At `startElement ()`, I'd get the name, and if it was `tag`, I'd add the `toString ()` of the `StringBuilder` and delete its contents.

Comment: @anonymous: that should work, but the stringbuilder shouldn't have to be static