# problem with using SAX XML Parser

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I am using the SAX Parser for XML Parsing. The problem is for the following XML code:

```
<description>
Designer:Paul Smith Color:Plain Black Fabric/Composition:100% cotton        Weave/Pattern:pinpoint Sleeve:Long-sleeved Fit:Classic Front style:Placket front Back style:Side pleat back Collar:Classic/straight collar Button:Pearlescent front button Pocket:rounded chest pocket Hem:Rounded hem
</description>
```

I get this:

```
Designer:Paul Smith
Color:Plain Black
```

The other parts are missing. The same thing happens for a few other lines. Can anyone kindly tell me whats the problem with my approach ?

My code is given below:

Parser code:

```
try {
        /** Handling XML */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
        URL sourceUrl = new URL(
        "http://50.19.125.224/Demo/VeryGoodSex_and_the_City_S6E6.xml");

        /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
        MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler((ContentHandler) myXMLHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }
```

Object to hold XML parsed Info:

```
public class ParserObject {

String name=null;
String description=null;
String bitly=null; //single
String productLink=null;//single
String productPrice=null;//single
Vector<String> price=new Vector<String>();
}
```

Handler class:

```
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
throws SAXException {


    currentElement = false;


    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
    {
        xmlDataObject[index].name=currentValue;
    }

    else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("artist"))
    {
        xmlDataObject[index].artist=currentValue;
    } 

}


public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {


    currentElement = true;

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("allinfo"))
    {
        System.out.println("started");
    }

    else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("tags"))
    {
        insideTag=1;
    } 

}

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
throws SAXException {

    if (currentElement) {
        currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
        currentElement = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAVA SAX parser split calls to characters()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567636/java-sax-parser-split-calls-to-characters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to concatenate characters which the parser gives to you until it calls `endElement`.

Try removing `currentElement = false;` from `characters` handler, and

```
currentValue = currentValue + new String(ch, start, length);
```

Initialize `currentValue` with an empty string or handle `null` value in the expression above.

Answer (score 1):

I think characters read some, but not all characters at the same time.
Thus, you only get the first "chunk".
Try printing each character chunk on a separate line, as debugging (before the if).