# How to parse XML by SAX and Create Tree list?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax, saxparser

I have learned a tutorial about SAX parser of java and now I need to create tree list of XML file like this:

```
<course>
     <chapter>
          <title>chapter one of course one</title>
          <content> .... </content>
     </chapter>

    <chapter>
          <title>chapter two of course one</title>
          <content> .... </content>
    </chapter>
</course>
```

and then I what to create data structure like this:

```
string lessons[][] = {
       {"chapter one of course one", "chapter two of course one"},
       {"chapter one of course two", "chapter two of course two", "chapter tree of course two"},
       ....
       ....
```

}

Comment: This is not the place for us to write your code. You need to try it, and if you get an error we can help. If you have learned the tutorial, put it to good use.

Comment: Hmm, I don't need any code, I need a solution to implement it in Java. my problem is than when the parse read the document line by line and startElement() and character() is called, I haven't any way to add items to  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>. So my original problem is Data Structure, I don't know how to save data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out-of-box support in JDK for the kind of data structure you are looking for. What you need is a [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). [Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) provides this data structure. You can either use that library (I recommend) or build your own.

Also, make sure you [read my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567636/java-sax-parser-split-calls-to-characters) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567636/java-sax-parser-split-calls-to-characters) SO post if your are reading element content using SAX.

[JAVA SAX parser split calls to characters()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567636/java-sax-parser-split-calls-to-characters)

Comment: Your answer saved my time this day. I saved my data to  ArrayListMultimap data structure.

Answer (score 0):

here you go: [THIS](http://www.saxproject.org/quickstart.html) is SAX documentation, read and try to build your own parser mate

Answer (score 0):

Think in terms of a a  [Stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29). In startElement() you push and in endElement you pop(). Depending on the element tag name you do interesting stuff with what's on the stack and perhaps also what you have in a "global" context.

Comment: This is another solution to this problem, I have to implement it, may be it is be better solution instead of using MultiMap structure.

Answer (score 0):

This code exactly does what you're looking for, You just need to tweak it to output the JSON structure you want.

https://github.com/kasmodia/sax-tree-parser