# java parser sax doesn't get value &amp; on my field

Tags: java

I have more elements on my xml file contains & and others characters html >.

I tested my code but it obtain the first part of my field for example:

```
 SERIES &amp; FILMS
```

It give only the word SERIES.

And other example:

```
C&gt;SUDO
```

It give only C.

My code, my field name is "summary":

```
   try {

     SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
     SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
     chars = new StringBuffer();
     DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {



     public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
     String qName, Attributes attributes)
     throws SAXException {

     System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);

     if (qName.equals(SUMMARY2)) {
     bfSummary = true;
     }
     if (qName.equals(SERVICE_DATA)) {
     idServiceData = attributes.getValue("id");
     bfServicedata = true;

     }

     }

     public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
     String qName) throws SAXException {

     System.out.println("End Element :" + qName + ""
     + mListBaseLineByEpgId.size());

     // maliste.put(listeId, summary);
     malisteParThem.add(summary);
     if (mListBaseLineByEpgId.get(idServiceData) != null) {
     List<String> listeModif = mListBaseLineByEpgId
     .get(idServiceData);
     for (String chaine : malisteParThem) {
     listeModif.add(chaine);
     }
     mListBaseLineByEpgId.replace(idServiceData, listeModif);
     } else {

     mListBaseLineByEpgId.put(idServiceData, malisteParThem);
     }
     malisteParThem = new ArrayList<String>();

     }

     public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
     throws SAXException {

     if (bfSummary) {
     summary = new String(ch, start, length);
     summary = summary.replace(BEFORETILESUMMARY, "");
     // chars.append(summary);
     // summary=chars.toString();
     summary = removeHtmlFrom(summary);
     System.out.println("Summary : " + summary);
     bfSummary = false;
     }
     if (bfServicedata) {
     System.out.println("listeId : " + idServiceData);
     bfServicedata = false;
     }

     }

     };
     File file = new File(cheminFichier);
     InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
     Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

     InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
     //is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
     saxParser.parse(is, handler);

     } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Thank you.

Comment: can't you please edit your code and add same indentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this problem is related to the unexpected behavior of SAX parser: it is allowed (per spec) to split the text part of an element and call `characters()` method multiple times for the same element.

What you need to do is have a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` instance variable.  You initialize it in `startElement()`, append to it on `characters()` and get the full text on `endElement()`

see this question for more info [JAVA SAX parser split calls to characters()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567636/java-sax-parser-split-calls-to-characters)