# Java XML parser executes each node twice

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax

I try to parse an XML file with a class I found on the internet. Only problem is that it passes twice by each node. First time it return the real value and null on the second time. Which makes the final value null. Here is the code of the parser class:

```
public class MyXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler{
private String node = null;
int i = 0;
   int j = 0;
   int k = 0;
   boolean cont = true;

public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    System.out.println("Début du parsing");
}

public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String lname, String qname, Attributes attrs) throws SAXException {
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("qname = " + qname);
    node = qname;

}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)throws SAXException{
    System.out.println("Fin de l'élément " + qName);      
    }

public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
    System.out.println("Fin du parsing");
}


public void characters(char[] data, int start, int end){  
   System.out.println("***********************************************");
   String rep ="";
   String str = new String(data, start, end);


   System.out.println("Donnée du nœud " + node + " : " + str);


}
```

}

and this is the server Slave that executes the parsing:

```
public class ServerEsclave implements Runnable{


private final Socket socket;
private  ServerSocket serverSocket;
private ServerMaitre serverMaitre;
ServerEsclave(Socket socket, ServerSocket serveur){
    this.socket = socket;
    this.serverSocket = serveur;
}

ServerEsclave(Socket socket, ServerMaitre serverMaitre) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.socket = socket;
    this.serverMaitre = serverMaitre;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "8859_1"), 1024);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        InputStream ch = socket.getInputStream();
        //sb.append(input.readLine());
        //System.out.println(sb);
        //String[] commande = sb.toString().split(" ");
        try {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

            parser.parse(ch, new MyXMLHandler());

            }catch (DOMException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}
        finally {
            try { if(socket != null) socket.close();}
            catch(IOException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

XML code that I want to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<Request>
   <ReqName> LIST </ReqName>
   <Dir>/home/abdou/Bureau</Dir>   
   <MailAddress>abderrahmen.mrabet@edu.univ-paris13.fr</MailAddress>
</Request>
```

And finally this is what I get on the console

### Début du parsing

qname = Request

---

Donnée du nœud Request :

---

qname = ReqName

---

Donnée du nœud ReqName : LIST
Fin de l'élément ReqName

---

Donnée du nœud ReqName :

---

qname = Dir

---

Donnée du nœud Dir : /home/abdou/Bureau
Fin de l'élément Dir

---

Donnée du nœud Dir :

---

qname = MailAddress

---

Donnée du nœud MailAddress : abderrahmen.mrabet@edu.univ-paris13.fr
Fin de l'élément MailAddress

---

Donnée du nœud MailAddress :

Fin de l'élément Request
Fin du parsing

---

You can clearly see that he passes twice by each node and the secon value he prints in null.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's because the `characters(...)` event is not triggered once,it "splits" the char data. For example, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567636/java-sax-parser-split-calls-to-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For futur viewers. This bug was, as potame said, due to the fact that the characters(...) event is not triggered once,it "splits" the char data.

Comment: You should have been printing that in `startElement()`. There is no reason to believe every element only contains one set of characters.